# Drupal Content Type & Views - Expose CCK fields - Edit Form

Tags: drupal

How can I achieve the following:

I have created a content type called journal, containing:
- Body
- Imagefield

What I would like to create a view that exposes the NODE create form for the juornal Content Type. In such a way that I can embed a block into a page, so that it then exposes the Body field as an empty box & the imagefield as a button to ad images. To allow a user to then just type text into the box, add an image and then click save.

Similiar real life example - http://drupal.org/project/fbsmp
The reason I dont ant to use this is because the node to be created will be part of a Organic Group and must be referenced to only that particular Organic GRoup, which can be dnoe with a simple node.

thanks 
Charles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Charles,

Is this what you're looking for?

http://drupal.org/project/formblock

Erik